# how to add products in magento 1.9 in front end

Tags: magento

Now i have installed magento 1.9 .

My page look like this https://i.stack.imgur.com/0XB84.jpg

I want to know how to add products without using sample data.

Can you help me?

Comment: `Catalog -> manage products -> add new product`?

Comment: @GerarddeVisser: Ihave added in backend.. but it doesn't show in front end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GO to **Catalog- Products - Manage Products** click on **Add Product** button in right top.
Insert all required fields.
To display in front end it must be in stock so go to inventory select **In Stock** and  **Quantity** greater than zero
.
And It must be added to a category to display in category view [to add a category go to **Catalog - Manage categories** ] or else to view the product you might need to search for it.

Comment: I have added kitchware as root category and food processor as sub category. now i want to show in front end as kitchenware . when hover over kitchenware it show food processor. when click the food processor it show the image and details of product. how to do that?

Comment: how exactly you want to display?

Comment: Already you seen lot of websites related magento right. thats like. in header should have menus, sidebar,,etc.

Comment: By default u can not display products in magento home page. you can only display categories. If you want to display them u need to create your custom module. But You can display New Products using inbuilt widget.

Comment: Is it displaying Food Processor category in front end?

Comment: kitchenware as root and food proceed sub of kitchenware.

Comment: ya ok. It wont display root category in front end. Is it displaying the sub category Food Proceed in the front end?

Comment: That is a category, that means you are displaying the category right? Or still do you want to display the products of that particular category?

Comment: Then you are done displaying the category.  http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/tutorial-creating-and-managing-categories

Comment: it doesn't show in home page. when i searched , then only displayed.

Comment: As I said Products will not be shown in home page by default. Only categories are displayed. And when u click the category the all the products associated to the category are displayed. Is the product displaying when u click on the category name?

Comment: first of all, foodprocesor is category name right?. it doesn't show in home page

Comment: By default it displays the Default Root Category to change it go to System->Manage Store->Main Web Site Store then select which root category u want to display in the front end. Only one root category can be displayed.

Comment: This your comment is not related to this question. And Please clear with you question.

Answer (score 0):

the best place to find information about the general setting up of Magento is the Magento Knowledge Base.  As for adding products, I recommend adding categories first so that visitors can navigate to the products.  The article for that is at http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/tutorial-creating-and-managing-categories.  Once you have categories, they can be assigned to products as they are added following the article at http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/1_-_installation_and_configuration/adding-a-new-product.

To show products from a specific category, get the category ID from admin, and include it on your home page's CMS content using the code (changing the category ID of course):

```
{{block type="catalog/product_list" name="home.catalog.product.list" alias="products_homepage" category_id="4" template="catalog/product/list.phtml"}}
```